# Best way to find highest number of times a 1d array is repeated in a 2d array

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a 2d array called Positions and I want to find the highest number of times an array is repeated within Positions.  The elements of the arrays in Positions are all integers.

As an example:

If Positions = [[1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3], [1,1,1,1,1]]

The algorithm should return 2, as [1,1,1,1,1] occurs twice in Positions.

I'm going to have called this function a lot for the project I'm working on, so I wanted to know the fastest way to do this.

Comment: How large is the range of the values inside each list? Could you convert / hash it to a single, larger integer, and keep track of the current count for each integer as your positions list change? How does the position list change? How often? How large can it be? "The fastest way" should usually be interpreted as "a fast enough way", as there's always some way to do something faster.

Comment: Do integers always repeat within a 1d array or can they be different e.g. `[ [1, 4, 5, 5, 3], [2, 1, 7, 6, 3] ...]`

Comment: no arrays within positions are altered, arrays are only added to or removed from positions. i don't have experience with hashing algorithms.   each list contains 64 values.  also the numbers don't always repeat, you could have [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simplest approach is to use the `max` and `count` functions:

```
>>> Positions = [[1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3], [1,1,1,1,1]]
>>> max(Positions.count(a) for a in Positions)
2
```

If you have some flexibility over how you track `Positions` (i.e. if they don't need to be lists and could instead be something immutable and/or hashable) you could make this dramatically more efficient.  If `Positions` is constantly changing underneath you it's more difficult to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it `O(n)`:

```py
res={}

for el in Positions:
    res[tuple(el)]=res.get(tuple(el), 0)+1

print(max(res.values()))
```

Which in your case returns `2`

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you want to count then it's good to look at what `collections.Counter` brings to the table.
Counter needs hasable types to count so I convert each inner list into a tuple for counting then use `Counter.most_common()` to do the heavy lifting.

```
In [93]: from collections import Counter

In [94]: Positions = [[1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3], [1,1,1,1,1]]

In [95]: item, count = Counter(tuple(x) for x in Positions).most_common(1)[0]

In [96]: list(item)
Out[96]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

In [97]: count
Out[97]: 2

In [98]:
```